# how to send data with php?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to send player id to delete and update page and it doesn't send it.

i'm adding my table body here.

```
              <tr>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $readRow['Photo']; ?>" width='64px'></td>
                <td> <?php echo$readRow['ID']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo$readRow['Fname']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $readRow['Lname']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo$readRow['Age']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo$readRow['Email']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo$readRow['Phone']; ?></td>
                <td><a href='update.php?id=$readRow[ID]' data-toggle="modal" data- 
                        target="#editplayer" class = 'btn btn-success'>Edit</a>
                <a href="delete.php" name = "Delete"  class = 'btn btn-danger'>Delete</a></td>
              </tr>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
```

please help.

Comment: I hope you don't let update and delete happen on GET requests, or web crawlers will follow the links and merrily delete all your data!

Answer (score 0):

You need `<?php echo ?>` around `$readRow[ID]`. And you need to put that into the `delete.php` URL as well.

```
              <tr>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $readRow['Photo']; ?>" width='64px'></td>
                <td> <?php echo$readRow['ID']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo$readRow['Fname']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $readRow['Lname']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo$readRow['Age']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo$readRow['Email']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo$readRow['Phone']; ?></td>
                <td><a href='update.php?id=<?php echo $readRow['ID']; ?>' data-toggle="modal" data- 
                        target="#editplayer" class = 'btn btn-success'>Edit</a>
                <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $readRow['ID']; ?>" name = "Delete"  class = 'btn btn-danger'>Delete</a></td>
              </tr>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add your id to be deleted as a GET parameter

```
 <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $readRow['ID']; ?>" name = "Delete"  class = 'btn btn-danger'>Delete</a></td>
```

However, I suggest you stay away from GET and use POST method, which is much more secure.

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<tr>
<td><img src="<?php echo $readRow['Photo']; ?>" width='64px'> 
// ...other td elements
</tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose player id with `<?php and ?>`  (PHP start and end tag respectively) as given below:

```
<a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $readRow['ID']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editplayer" class = 'btn btn-success'>Edit</a>
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $readRow['ID']; ?>" name = "Delete"  class = 'btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>
```